# RSpec, why did I have to place my subject in a lambda to get it to catch the exception?

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec, assertions

I don't understand why I had to do:

```
subject { lambda { JenkinsClient.new(params.tap{|p| p.delete(:password)}) } }
it { expect { subject.call }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
```

To get it to capture the raised exception instead of:

```
subject { JenkinsClient.new(params.tap{|p| p.delete(:password)}) }
it { expect { subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
```

Could someone provide insight into this?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the second example (with no lambda) does not work? What exception do you get?

Comment: I get the ArgumentError exception as I run the code, so it does not work as expected. The error is raised and stops the test, but isn't caught.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I wanted to show (with formatting) that the following works fine, so I don't think there is some fundamental RSpec issue in what you're experiencing:

```
describe "Subject raising error" do
  subject {raise ArgumentError}
  it {expect {subject}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)}
end
```